Bluetooth keyboard connected but not working after rezising partition
After messing with partitions* trying to get a dual boot with Kubuntu and NobaraOS, I resized my main Kubuntu partition to have more space and deleted the other partition as coudn't get it to work. That's when problems started. When I log in after reseting or sleeping my pc the wifi doesn't automatically connect, and the worst part, the keyboard doesn't work. I can only connect to it if I forget the device and re pair it. But then it doesn't work. If i disconnect and connect it again after re paring, it connects only when I type something but it doesn't work.
sudo btom outputs:
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.72
btmon[144343]: = Note: Linux version 6.8.0-41-generic (x86_64)                                        0.863664
btmon[144343]: = Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                                               0.863666
= New Index: C8:CB:9E:45:0D:70 (Primary,USB,hci0)                                              [hci0] 0.863667
= Open Index: C8:CB:9E:45:0D:70                                                                [hci0] 0.863667
= Index Info: C8:CB:9E:45:0D:70 (Intel Corp.)                                                  [hci0] 0.863668
bluetoothd[1329]: @ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.22                          {0x0001} 0.863668
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 44                                                   #1 [hci0] 2.910177
      LE Extended Advertising Report (0x0d)
        Num reports: 1
        Entry 0
          Event type: 0x0013
            Props: 0x0013
              Connectable
              Scannable
              Use legacy advertising PDUs
            Data status: Complete
          Legacy PDU Type: ADV_IND (0x0013)
          Address type: Random (0x01)
          Address: DB:EB:F8:89:54:5D (Static)
          Primary PHY: LE 1M
          Secondary PHY: No packets
          SID: no ADI field (0xff)
          TX power: 127 dBm
          RSSI: -53 dBm (0xcb)
          Periodic advertising interval: 0.00 msec (0x0000)
          Direct address type: Public (0x00)
          Direct address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (OUI 00-00-00)
          Data length: 0x12
        03 19 c1 03 02 01 06 03 03 12 18 06 ff 06 00 03  ................
        00 80                                            ..              
        Appearance: Keyboard (0x03c1)
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (complete): 1 entry
          Human Interface Device (0x1812)
        Company: Microsoft (6)
          Data: 030080
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) plen 6                             #2 [hci0] 2.910299
        Extended scan: Disabled (0x00)
        Filter duplicates: Disabled (0x00)
        Duration: 0 msec (0x0000)
        Period: 0.00 sec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                 #3 [hci0] 2.912156
      LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Extended Create Connection (0x08|0x0043) plen 26                          #4 [hci0] 2.912270
        Filter policy: Accept list is not used (0x00)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address type: Random (0x01)
        Peer address: DB:EB:F8:89:54:5D (Static)
        Initiating PHYs: 0x01
        Entry 0: LE 1M
          Scan interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
          Scan window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
          Min connection interval: 30.00 msec (0x0018)
          Max connection interval: 50.00 msec (0x0028)
          Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
          Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
          Min connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
          Max connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                   #5 [hci0] 2.914018
      LE Extended Create Connection (0x08|0x0043) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 31                                                   #6 [hci0] 2.992163
      LE Enhanced Connection Complete (0x0a)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 2048
        Role: Central (0x00)
        Peer address type: Random (0x01)
        Peer address: DB:EB:F8:89:54:5D (Static)
        Local resolvable private address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (Non-Resolvable)
        Peer resolvable private address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (Non-Resolvable)
        Connection interval: 45.00 msec (0x0024)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
        Central clock accuracy: 0x00
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 31                                       {0x0001} [hci0] 2.992222
        LE Address: DB:EB:F8:89:54:5D (Static)
        Flags: 0x00000008
          Connection Locally Initiated
        Data length: 18
        Appearance: Keyboard (0x03c1)
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (complete): 1 entry
          Human Interface Device (0x1812)
        Company: Microsoft (6)
          Data: 030080
btmon[144343]: @ RAW Open: btmon (privileged) version 2.22                                   {0x0002} 2.992424
btmon[144343]: @ RAW Close: btmon                                                            {0x0002} 2.992431
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 4                                                    #7 [hci0] 2.992856
      LE Channel Selection Algorithm (0x14)
        Handle: 2048 Address: DB:EB:F8:89:54:5D (Static)
        Algorithm: #2 (0x01)
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) plen 2                            #8 [hci0] 2.997145
        Handle: 2048 Address: DB:EB:F8:89:54:5D (Static)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                   #9 [hci0] 2.997852
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                                                  #10 [hci0] 3.065181
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 2048 Address: DB:EB:F8:89:54:5D (Static)
        Features: 0x05 0x41 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
          Extended Reject Indication
          LE 2M PHY
          Channel Selection Algorithm #2
< HCI Command: LE Start Encryption (0x08|0x0019) plen 28                                   #11 [hci0] 3.066105
        Handle: 2048 Address: DB:EB:F8:89:54:5D (Static)
        Random number: 0x0000000000000000
        Encrypted diversifier: 0x0000
        Long term key: d791b06ae853105526976c5feb3f9e83
bluetoothd[1329]: = src/service.c:service_accept() input-hog profile accept failed for DB:EB:F8:8..   3.066387
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                  #12 [hci0] 3.066893
      LE Start Encryption (0x08|0x0019) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Encryption Change (0x08) plen 4                                               #13 [hci0] 3.334920
        Status: PIN or Key Missing (0x06)
        Handle: 2048 Address: DB:EB:F8:89:54:5D (Static)
        Encryption: Disabled (0x00)
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3                                             #14 [hci0] 3.335145
        Handle: 2048 Address: DB:EB:F8:89:54:5D (Static)
        Reason: Authentication Failure (0x05)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                  #15 [hci0] 3.335883
      Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4                                             #16 [hci0] 3.425144
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 2048 Address: DB:EB:F8:89:54:5D (Static)
        Reason: Connection Terminated By Local Host (0x16)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                                     {0x0001} [hci0] 3.425340
        LE Address: DB:EB:F8:89:54:5D (Static)
        Reason: Connection terminated due to authentication failure (0x04)
bluetoothd[1329]: = profiles/deviceinfo/deviceinfo.c:read_pnpid_cb() Error reading PNP_ID value:...   3.425723
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan Parameters (0x08|0x0041) plen 13                       #17 [hci0] 3.441333
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Ignore not in accept list (0x01)
        PHYs: 0x05
        Entry 0: LE 1M
          Type: Passive (0x00)
          Interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
          Window: 30.000 msec (0x0030)
        Entry 1: LE Coded
          Type: Passive (0x00)
          Interval: 180.000 msec (0x0120)
          Window: 90.000 msec (0x0090)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                #18 [hci0] 3.441878
      LE Set Extended Scan Parameters (0x08|0x0041) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) plen 6                            #19 [hci0] 3.442035
        Extended scan: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
        Duration: 0 msec (0x0000)
        Period: 0.00 sec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                #20 [hci0] 3.442835
      LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)

*By that I mean i went into KDE Partition manager and resized my Ubuntu partition to 300gb
Info about my linux:
OS: Kubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64
DE: Plasma 5.27.11

You say you messed with partitions, what ever that means. But your question does not have any info on what messing with means or did or the commands or methods you used. I do not even see a version of Ubuntu mentioned in this. Please edit the question and fill in some details.

@DavidDE Thanks for pointing it out. I updated the question to clarify and also added more information.

I found a solution.

holy smoke! I fixed this, after months of researching and poking
around.
hidp/uhid really IS the problem. I don't know what makes a Linux
decide to load uhid or hidp, my "good" and "bad" Linux SSD are dd'ed
from same source, and they even have same partition uuid.
long story short, force load uhid kernel module, all mice work (BLE
mode) happily now!
echo -e  "# Fix BLE mouse issue\nuhid" | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/uhid.conf
then reboot.
note: edited, blacklist hidp is not necessary, either does
UserspaceHID=true, just force load uhid

NOTE: I didn't reboot. I simply forgot the keyboard and then reconnected it.
Credits to: https://github.com/bluez/bluez/issues/531#issuecomment-1913058753
